# Two coloured background

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to set background of a plot to be coloured in such a way:

```
col = c("grey", "white")
par(bg = rep(col, length.out = 5))
```

So that `grey` and `white` lines would repeat `length.out` number of times?

Comment: It's probably simpler to draw rectangles / hack the gridlines into rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are after. If you want colour rectangles, then use `rect`

```
add_bg = function() rect(-3:2, -3,  -2:3, 3, col=1:2)
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(-3, 3), 
      bg=3,pch=21,cex=2, panel.first=add_bg())
```

to get a stripped effect. If you just want vertical lines, then use `grid`

```
no=10
## For horizontal lines set ny=no, nx=0
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(-3, 3), 
      bg=3,pch=21,cex=2, panel.first=grid(ny=0,nx=no, col=1:2))
```

In both examples, I used the `panel.first` argument. When the graph is drawn the grid/rectangles are placed behind the points.

Comment: can the first example be made to work regardless of the data scale?

Comment: @csgillespie Hello, Thank you for your answer! could be modified to horizontal lines instead of vertical?

Comment: @csgillespie Yes. i was able to modify for horizontal lines instead :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @baptiste What do you mean regardless of the data scale? Obviously you could pass argument to add_bg that would specify the number of rectangles to draw.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand your solution, but if you change the xlim in the plot, the rectangles don't span the full plot panel. That's what I mean: 5 rectangles in the background, regardless of the x/y scales.

Comment: Sorry for the dummy question :) but how to change color in your function? why its black and red :)

Comment: @Try those are the first two default colours in `?palette()`

Comment: `par("usr")` seems to do the trick, `add_bg = function(n=5, col=seq_len(n)) {
  lims <- par("usr");
  dx <- diff(c(lims[1], lims[2]))/n ;
  rect(seq(lims[1], lims[2]-dx, by=dx), lims[3], 
       seq(lims[1]+dx, lims[2], by=dx), lims[4], col=col)
}
`

Comment: @baptiste thank you very much for help! but could it be horizontal not vertical :)

Comment: @Try that was more of a follow-up for cgillepsie, but if you want to use it with horizontal lines, swap a few things around like so `add_bg = function(n=5, col=seq_len(n)) {
  lims <- par("usr");
  dy <- diff(c(lims[3], lims[4]))/n;
  rect( lims[1],seq(lims[3], lims[4]-dy, by=dy), 
        lims[2], seq(lims[3]+dy, lims[4], by=dy), col=col)
}`